# How to write a file in github from python code

Tags: python, dataframe

This code is working , ie, the path and file exists and has public access.

```
path='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jorge-chavez-salas/proyectosMINERIA/master/codigosCURSO'
ARCHIVO2 = pandas.read_csv(path)
print(ARCHIVO2)
```

But this code throws an error "No such file or directory:"

```
FILE=open(path,'wb')
DATA.to_csv(FILE)
```

Can someone please tell me why ? and how to solve it ?
I want to open a file and the rewrite it from a data frame. Thanks

Comment: `open` loads a file from the local file system, why should it behave otherwise? Why do you think `open` will download a file from the internet and open it?

Comment: This question needs clarity, I flagged it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in pandas **read_csv** you can pas url but **open** needs path to file.

Answer (score 0):

Well someone had already told you cant use `open` to url.
Better download  your data in some file and work on it

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jorge-chavez-salas/proyectosMINERIA/master/codigosCURSO'
r = requests.get(url)

filename = 'Your Desired filename'
open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
```